# JSON decode any value - $var1 = $data['val1']['anyvalue']['val2'];

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables, var

I am pulling in JSON data for a mySQL import and in setting the variables after my JSON decode statements of my JSON file I am struggling with something. My variable setting looks like so

```
$name = $data['available_channels']['3']['name'];
```

and the relevant JSON like this

```
"available_channels": {
    "3": {
      "num": 152,
      "name": "Sky Sports 3",
      "stream_type": "live",
      "type_name": "Live Streams",
      "stream_id": "3",
      "stream_icon": "http://www.tv-logo.com/pt-data/uploads/images/logo/sky_uk_sports3.jpg",
      "epg_channel_id": "Sky Sports 3",
      "added": "0",
      "category_name": "Sports UK",
      "category_id": "5",
      "series_no": null,
      "live": "1",
      "container_extension": null,
      "custom_sid": ":0:86:EEE:7F2:2:11A0000:0:0:0:",
      "tv_archive": 0,
      "direct_source": "",
      "tv_archive_duration": 0
    },
```

My problem is that each channel for the service begins with a new number. So i need my variables to be pulled in like so,

```
$name = $data['available_channels']['ANY VALUE HERE']['name'];
```

any thoughts? I know it must be simple and I am having a blonde moment here

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

```
//convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    //get the values and asign variables
    $name = $data['available_channels']['3']['name'];
```

**UPDATE 2**

Full Code Now

```html
    $data = json_decode($jsonFile, true);
    
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($data['available_channels']); $i++){
    $name = $data['available_channels'][$i]['name'];
    $num = $data['available_channels'][$i]['num'];
    $epg_channel_id = $data['available_channels'][$i]['epg_channel_id'];
    $category_name = $data['available_channels'][$i]['category_name'];
    $stream_icon = $data['available_channels'][$i]['stream_icon'];
    
    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO channels(name, num, epg_channel_id, category_name, stream_icon)
    VALUES('$name', '$num', '$epg_channel_id', '$category_name', '$stream_icon')";
    if(!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     
    
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Gets about 117 of 234 rows in but the other rows are blank... any thoughts

Comment: what is the problem?you can put any value there

Comment: You are trying to reference a object like an array. Try `$data->something->otherthing` or `$data = json_decode( $data , 1 )`

Comment: so it pulls through in a loop atm. everything is great but instead of it being where the second value in the decode is 3 I need it to be where that value = anything

Comment: have a quick look at the code now at the bottom... The $data variable is pulled from a json decode

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = array_values($data['available_channels'])[0]['name'];
```

[`array_values`](http://php.net/array-values) returns a new array consisting of the values of the source array, renumbered from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of channels inside the array, then loop through each channel.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($data['available_channels']); $i++) {
    $name = $data['available_channels'][$i]['name'];
    // TODO: Do something with the name
}
```

Or you could do what @cske said:

```
$channels = [];
foreach($data['available_channels'] as $k => $v) {
    // this will keep the key's the same
    $channels[$k] = $v['name'];
}
```

Or you could choose a more OO styled approach, see it working at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Ja8fb):

```
class Channel {
    private $_data;
    public function __construct($json) {
        $this->_data = json_decode($json, true);
    }

    public function parse() {
        $parsed = [];
        foreach($this->_data['available_channels'] as $k => $v) {
            $parsed[$k] = $v['name'];
        }
        $this->_data['available_channels'] = $parsed;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getByKey($key) {
        return $this->_data['available_channels'][$key];
    }
}

$c = new Channel($json_response);
echo 'Name for Channel 3 is: ' . $c->parse()->getByKey('3');
```

Comment: with `foreach` not assuming consecutive numbering same result `foreach ($data['available_channels'] as $d) {
    $name = $d['name'];
}`

Comment: yes, you could even use a while loop. I prefer `for()` so I used it @cske

Comment: not the same if `$data['available_channels`]` keys are '1,2,5` then `for` will throw an error

Comment: no it won't because index's start at 0 and we're going off index's not keys @cske

Comment: `if($i >= 3) { ... }` - use your common sense @cske

Comment: ok ok calm your horses haha... that value can be any integer not only 3+ its just 3 is the first...

I've posted my updated code in UPDATE 2, so would appreciate some help looking at that as wondering why it's only pulling half of them through, and the other rows as blank

Comment: getting some undefined offsets in lines `$name` and below on the loop

Comment: check if it empty before storing it then using the `isset()` and `empty()` functions @HenryAspden

Comment: i just don't understand why it would be empty... if I print my $data its all there

Comment: could be an offset key, not just the name @HenryAspden

Answer (score 0):

So after update 2, this will work

```
foreach($data['available_channels'] as $d) {
    $name           = $d['name'];
    $num            = $d['num'];
    $epg_channel_id = $d['epg_channel_id'];
    $category_name  = $d['category_name'];
    $stream_icon    = $d['stream_icon'];

    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO channels(name, num, epg_channel_id, category_name, stream_icon)
    VALUES('$name', '$num', '$epg_channel_id', '$category_name', '$stream_icon')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Or if with for loop @KDOT answer, but corrected by @Niet the Dark Absol code

```
$data['available_channels'] = array_values($data['available_channels']);
for($i = 0; $i <= count($data['available_channels']); $i++) {
   $name           = $data['available_channels'][$i]['name'];
   ...
}
```

That is simply not true if a php array has count()=5  then it's keys are 0,1,2,3,4 what couses missing rows with KDOT's answer